# SSLCertVerificationError is caught by ValueError and not OSError

Tags: python

We had a bug I'm trying to understand why happened.

In the documentation it is mentioned that SSLError a subtype of OSError.
(https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLError)

However this code doesn't work as expected - it seems that ValueError wins over

```
def bar():
    raise ssl.SSLCertVerificationError

try:
    bar()
except ValueError:
    print('Got ValueError')
except OSError:
    print('Got OSError')
```

The above results to `Got ValueError`

Couldn't find any documented bug around this
Python version - Python 3.8.9

Comment: Same problem in 3.6.2. Very interesting. This looks like a bug indeed (or incorrect documentation).

Comment: Note: it's whichever's first that gets caught - i.e. if you swap your Value and OS Error catch blocks over you'll see OSErrors are caught. Both `issubclass(ssl.SSLCertVerificationError, OSError)` and ` issubclass(ssl.SSLCertVerificationError, ValueError)` return true.

Comment: Also: whilst `SSLCertVerificationError` is a subcalss of both, `SSLError` is not.  `inspect.getmro(ssl.SSLCertVerificationError)` gives `(<class 'ssl.SSLCertVerificationError'>, <class 'ssl.SSLError'>, <class 'OSError'>, <class 'ValueError'>, <class 'Exception'>, <class 'BaseException'>, <class 'object'>)`

Comment: @JohnLBevan - so is it indeed a python bug? Should be reported?

Comment: I don't know Python well enough to say, so will leave to someone who knows/regularly uses that language.  I know Python allows multiple inheritence and I can see that the SSLCertVerificationError class inherits from both OSError (probbaly via SSLError) and ValueError; so it seems to do what you'd expect.  The documentation says that SSLError inherits from OSError, so is correct.  The only misleading bit is the implication that SSLCertVerificationError is an alias for SSLError, whilst in fact it's a subclass with an additional superclass.

Comment: OK - actually your second comment should count as an answer... so if you add it as an answer I'll accept it (it answers my question)

Comment: @JohnLBevan- seems it's intentional. From the comment it looks like they didn't want to break backward compatibility
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c340cbb7f74bc99eaf72d6a4ef5b4d504d8519c8/Modules/_ssl.c#L5640
sucks it caused a bug for us...

Comment: @Boaz Ah good find :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're getting this behaviour because `SSLCertVerificationError` extends both `OSError` and `ValueError`.

i.e. running [inspect's getmro](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmro) on this class...:

```py
import ssl
import inspect
inspect.getmro(ssl.SSLCertVerificationError)
```

...gives this

- `<class 'ssl.SSLCertVerificationError'>`
- `<class 'ssl.SSLError'>`
- `<class 'OSError'>`
- `<class 'ValueError'>`
- `<class 'Exception'>`
- `<class 'BaseException'>`
- `<class 'object'>`

Python supports multipe inheritence; i.e. whilst in many languages a class only has one immediate parent (which may itself have one parent), in Python, a class may have several immediate parents (super classes).
Looking at `SSLError`, that inherits from `OSError` but doesn't from `ValueError`; so it seems that `SSLCertVerificationError`'s immediate parents are `ssl.Error` and `ValueError`.

i.e. `inspect.getmro(ssl.SSLError)` returns:

- `<class 'ssl.SSLError'>`
- `<class 'OSError'>`
- `<class 'Exception'>`
- `<class 'BaseException'>`
- `<class 'object'>`

Given `SSLCertVerificationError` inherits from both `OSError` (via `SSLError`) and `ValueError` it seems Python will use whichever catch block comes first; as demonstrated with the 2 examples below.

```py
def bar():
    raise ssl.SSLCertVerificationError

try:
    bar()
except ValueError:
    print('I win (Value Error)')
except OSError:
    print('already handled above (OS Error)')
```

```py
def bar():
    raise ssl.SSLCertVerificationError

try:
    bar()
except OSError:
    print('I win (OS Error)')
except ValueError:
    print('already handled above (Value Error)')
```

Were you to replace `raise ssl.SSLCertVerificationError` with `raise ssl.SSLError` you'd only see the `except OSError` logic in play as the `ValueError` wouldn't be part of the object's inheritence hierarchy.

Note: I don't really know Python; so can't say for certain whether the above's the behaviour expected according to the language's design; but the above behaviour does make sense given what we can show about its inheritence.